# Word for a person who succumbed to their bad habits

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm looking for a single English word that refers to:

- A person who has bad habits
- And used to do those bad habits
- Tried to escape them but then fell into them in perpetua

I'm not sure if such a word exists. I've thought of:

- Hypocrite (but that doesn't contain any connotations of habit)
- Habitual (an adjective; whereas I want a noun)

Any ideas? I'm pretty sure there's a word for a person who relapsed back into their bad habits.

Comment: "Back-slider" is one term I've heard used.

Comment: How about "dead."  -- at least in extreme cases.

Comment: Turn "habitual" from an adjective into a noun: habituer ;-)

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps **[relapser](https://www.wordnik.com/words/relapser).**

> n. One who relapses, as into vice or error.

It is usually related with illnesses but it is also used for people who relapses back into addictions. There is a term called "**chronic relapser**" for these kind of addicts as well.

---

---

From [Addiction Professional](http://www.addictionpro.com/article/help-chronic-relapser) magazine:

> Numerous failed attempts at sobriety, or **a return to drugs/alcohol after a substantial period of sobriety.**
>
> While this is a simple and obvious criterion of **a chronic relapser**, the distinction of an individual who has attempted sobriety and failed is important.
>
> Many addicts have a lifetime of drug and alcohol abuse but have never actually attempted to get sober. What makes chronic relapsers distinct is that they have tried and failed.

Comment: I was tempted by that one, too.  But, I couldn't find it in any reputable dictionaries.

Comment: I was tempted first also but then I read about chronic relapsers and it perfectly fits. Also the verb "relapse" means to fall back into bad habits.

Comment: This is actually something that people will easily understand from the word itself, which works very well for my needs. +1

Answer (score 16):

A **recidivist** is someone who has a relapse into a habit such as substance abuse or criminality.

It does not inherently imply a will to escape the bad behavior, but it does imply that some bad effects have been experienced as a result of their actions (such as jail time).

Examples of use with respect to gambling [here](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/she-bets-her-life/201002/womens-secret-addiction-powerful-crack-cocaine-more-deadlyand-its-lega) and [here](http://alcoholrehab.com/alcohol-rehab/recidivism-after-rehab/).

With respect to smoking [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8483864) and [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030646037890028X).

There are many examples with respect to drugs and criminal behavior, but those two tend to get mixed up since much such substance abuse is illegal.

Comment: I think "recidivism" is a more encompassing word than a "recidivist". Recidivist is mostly used related to criminals. Though there is "recidivist drink driver" term that is mainly used in Australia and New Zealand, I suppose.

Comment: Is this actually a commonly used term? It seems a bit archaic.

Comment: @ashes999 Yes, its a commonly used term (at least recidivism is). I've added links to examples that are not connected to criminality.

Comment: @ashes999 This is used in the US as almost the standard word for this concept AFAIK.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate the help. I feel that for my target audience, this word may be less easily understood than `relapser`, so I chose that as the final answer.

Answer (score 8):

At one time *backslide*, *backsliding*, *backslider* were quite common:

[image: Ngram: backslider,relapser, recidivist]

The primary sense was from the outset religious—“apostate”— (see various translations of chapter 14, verse 14 of the Book of Proverbs, [including the King James translation](http://www.blueletterbible.org/search/search.cfm?Criteria=backslider&t=KJV#s=s_primary_0_1), but it has long been used for return to less specifically theological misfeasances, as in this from *The Bristol Temperance Herald* for January, 1855:

[image: Temperance backsliders]

And it's still current;  you don't get much hipper than Seinfeld, when Elaine 'bumps into' her ex-boyfriend:

> PUDDY: Hey Benes, How are you?
>   ELAINE: I’m doing great.
>   PUDDY: Great. (pauses) See ya.
>   JERRY: Well, that’s it. You two are back together.
>   ELAINE: What?
>   JERRY: The bump into. The bump into always leads to the backslide.
>   ELAINE: David and I will not be getting back together.
>   JERRY: Elaine, breaking up is like knocking over a coke machine. You can’t do it in one push, you got to rock it back and forth a few times, and then it goes over.
>   GEORGE: That’s beautiful.
>   ELAINE: What about you? You were even engaged, and you cut it off just like that.
>   JERRY: That’s different. I didn’t have feelings for those people. But you, you’ll backslide

Comment: It doesn't seem like `backslider` is a real word, though.

Comment: @ashes999 Sure it is - just Google it. You'll find it all over descriptions of drug rehabilitation programs, for example. I used Seinfeld only because it's such a different register.

Answer (score 2):

You can call them **the relapsed**.

For example:

> There is little help available for the relapsed (heroin addict).

This is similar to calling them **the fallen**.  Which might be a bit poetic for your use, but it would work, as well.

Comment: True, although this refers to a group, not a singular.

Comment: @ashes999 without a modifier, yes. If you add the modifier -heroin addict, it becomes a singular.

Comment: Nice try, but I'm looking for a single word :)

Comment: @ashes999 they can't all be winners. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the other answers are right but I think the word is simply an **addict**.

Comment: An addict doesn't necessarily want to break his/her unhealthy habit or vice. They can be in self-denial about their addiction, or simply prefer to continue.

Comment: @Mari-Lou As much as it pains me to agree with my frenemy Ryebread:  iaddicts don't have to quit to be called addicts. But, statistically once they do quit, they will relapse at some point.  I don't think it's a perfect fit, but belongs on the list of synonyms.

Comment: @DavidM the question specifies a person who tries to quit but succumbs to the bad habit(s). The word, addict, does not convey this. A smoker can be unrepentant, and be perfectly content to continue with his/her "vice".

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't disagree with you.  I'm just saying that they are *all* addicts.  Hence, it can be used as a descriptor.  It's just not narrow enough to be the accepted answer.  (Hence, a synonym to it.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Given the criteria addict is the most common term.  The pure definition doesn't mean a person who wants to quit their bad habit but that is the connotation of the word.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd Why am I defending *your* answer?!?  ;-)

Comment: @DavidM - because you are a wise delegate, maybe even a prophet.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd I would say I'm generally more of an apostate.

Comment: addict is a subset of bad habits, but bad habits are not a subset of addiction

Comment: I agree with this synonym. If someone has a habit they consider harmful, they try to stop, but they find they cannot then I would think of them as addicted.

Answer (score 2):

Degenerate as a noun.

He is pretty scruffy, even for a degenerate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word "incorrigible" works fairly well.

Comment: It's not a noun. See my list of requirements.